# Appending DataFrames in Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, append

Goal: Appending DataFrames in Loop to get combined dataframe.

```
df_base = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_col.columns)
file_path = 'DATA/'
filenames = ['savedrecs-23.txt', 'savedrecs-25.txt', 'savedrecs-24.txt']
```

For-Loop:

```
for file in filenames:
    path = file_path+file
    doc = codecs.open(path,'rU','UTF-8')

    df_add = pd.read_csv(doc, sep='\t')
    res = df_base.append(df_add)

res.shape
```

Expected Outcome:
(**15**, 67) ; all three data frames merged into one dataframe

Current Outcome:
(**5**, 67) ; just returns the last dataframe in the loop.

Comment: hmm use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) otherwise replace `res` with `df_base`

Comment: What is `df_base` in this code? it doesn't look like it is defined. Perhaps you want `df_base = df_base.append(df_add)`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

> res = df_base.append(df_add)

Pandas `append` function does not modify the object it is called on. It returns a new object that contains the rows from the added dataframe appended onto the rows of the original dataframe.

Since you never modified `df_base`, so your output is just the frame from the last file, appended to the empty `df_base` dataframe.

Note that the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) doesn't recommend iteratively appending dataframes together. Instead, "a better solution is to append those rows to a list and then concatenate the list with the original DataFrame all at once." (with an example given)

Comment: Thank you! But considering this, the following code should work: df_base = df_base.append(df_add)

Comment: @thetinywindow, yes it should work, but might be inefficient if you need to work with bigger data sets.