# Append dataframes in a for-loop within a function

Tags: r, dataframe, function, append

Toy dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  country = factor(c('USA', 'USA', 'Japan')),
  dimension = factor(c('economic', 'cultural', 'religious')))
```

I attempt to write a function to collect level names for all factors in df:

```
collect_levels <- function(df) {
  for (col in colnames(df)){
    name = col
    levels = levels(df[[col]])
    all_levels = data.frame(name, levels)
    print(all_levels)
  }
}
```

Trying the function:

```
collect_levels(df)
```

Will output:

```
     name levels
1 country  Japan
2 country    USA
       name    levels
1 dimension  cultural
2 dimension  economic
3 dimension religious
```

But what I want is a single df, like this:

```
     name levels
1 country  Japan
2 country    USA
3 dimension  cultural
4 dimension  economic
5 dimension religious
```

I have tried:

```
collect_levels <- function(df) {
  for (col in colnames(df)){
    name = col
    levels = levels(df[[col]])
    all_levels = list(data.frame(name, levels))
    final_object = bind_rows(all_levels)
    print(final_object)
  }
}
```

But this does not work.

Likewise [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420226/appending-dataframes-in-loop) might be related, but I cannot manage to make it work in my case.

Comment: `dplyr::distinct(tidyr::pivot_longer(df, everything()), name, value)`

Comment: `print()`ing is very different than `return()`ing. What you assume is a `list` is not a `list`, it's just stuff printed in your console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
collect_levels <- function(dat)  {
  isfac <- sapply(dat, is.factor)
  dplyr::bind_rows(
    lapply(dat[isfac], function(z) tibble::enframe(unique(z), value = "levels")[-1]),
    .id = "name")
}
collect_levels(df)
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#   name      levels   
#   <chr>     <fct>    
# 1 country   USA      
# 2 country   Japan    
# 3 dimension economic 
# 4 dimension cultural 
# 5 dimension religious
```

Comment: Or `purrr::map_dfr(dat, \(z) tibble::enframe(unique(z), value = "levels")[-1], .id = "name")` (+1)

Comment: Many thanks. I would like to apply this only to factors and ordered factors in my df. How would I do? I believe current solution does not work if other data types (e.g., dates) are in df.

Comment: Thanks r2Evans and Axeman, but these solutions only work if the df has only factors.

Comment: okay, then you can simply subset inside the function @johnjohn. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

in base R you could do:

```
setNames(rev(stack(lapply(df, levels))), c("name", "levels"))

       name    levels
1   country     Japan
2   country       USA
3 dimension  cultural
4 dimension  economic
5 dimension religious
```

You fist use `lapply(df, levels)` to get all the levels, then you `stack` them together. you can then rename and `rev`erse the order:

ie

```
stack(lapply(df, levels))
     values       ind
1     Japan   country
2       USA   country
3  cultural dimension
4  economic dimension
5 religious dimension
```

Is half way there. Only different Names and the order

Comment: many thanks for this alternative solution!